# Use shell command from vim to open files in open vim session

Tags: shell, vim, plugins

I am trying to open the files from a `find` command from within a `vim` session in new tabs.

For example, from my VIM session I want the results from this command `:r! find ~/mydir -type f -iname myfiles` to each open in a new tab.

So it's similar to doing `vim -p $(find ~/mydir -type f -iname myfiles)` except it's from an already running session.

Plugin recommendations that handle this type of problem also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the job:

```
command! -nargs=*  OpenResults  for f in systemlist(<q-args>) | exe "tabe ".f | endfor
```

Run it like this:

```
:OpenResults find ~/mydir -type f -iname myfiles
```

**Quick details**:
It uses `systemlist()` which returns the output of a shell command as a list; a `for` loop over this list lets the command open a tab for each returned filename.